# not able to fetch a value from response array

Tags: karate

I have a response body as below.

{
"issue": [{
"reason": "SELECTED ITEMS WERE ISSUED",
"isSuccess": true
}]
}

I want to validate  : reason  = "SELECTED ITEMS WERE ISSUED" and isSuccess = true.

I tried this :

- assert response.issue[0].reason == 'SELECTED ITEMS WERE ISSUED'
- match response.issue[0].isSuccess == true

but always get this error
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot get property "0" of null in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly for me, paste these 3 lines into any test and see for yourself:

```
* def response = { "issue": [{ "reason": "SELECTED ITEMS WERE ISSUED", "isSuccess": true }] }
* match response.issue[0].reason == 'SELECTED ITEMS WERE ISSUED'
* match response.issue[0].isSuccess == true
```

Comment: I found the error . i missed one more json object when doing json parsing . it will be response.data.issue[0]. Thank you for your quick response. Much appreciated!! Love the framework.